# IEnumerable list not reordering string[] list correctly

Tags: c#, linq, list, xna, ienumerable

I have a `string[]` list that contains arrays.

The arrays contain two elements, [0] = score, [1] = difficulty (1 or 2).

I use the following `LINQ` statement to reorder the list by the scores in descending order where the difficulty is 2.

```
scoresDesHard = list.OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]).Where(ld => lineData[1] == "2");
```

I am currently drawing the newly ordered list to the screen in `XNA` like so:

```
// draw highscores to the screen
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{

    string mainString = "";

    // build the hard list string
    foreach (var li in scoresDesHard)
    {

        mainString += li[0] + " " + li[1] + "\r\n";
    }

    spriteBatch.DrawString(scoreFont, ""+ mainString, hardScoresPos, Color.White);
}
```

It hasn't ordered the list at all and is showing scores from both difficulties:

```
000001 1
000001 2
122122 1
125555 1
22 1
23131 2
```

It should be outputting:

```
23131 2
00001 2
```

Why is it failing to order the list?

Comment: Your query should work. Make sure you are enumerating results after filtering was applied. Side question - why use strings if both score and difficulty are numeric?

Comment: Are you sure there are not 2 variables `scoresDesHard` by accident? One declared in the method where it is set, and one on a larger scope?

Comment: String ordering is lexicographic, you need to order by the numeric value of the score. You should create your own type instead of representing things as string arrays.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Good point I will change it to an int list. What do you mean by "enumerating results"?

Comment: Please post some actual code. The linq query you posted is not even valid

Comment: @crm enumerating results is enumerating `scoresDesHard` in `foreach` loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are passing ld into the Lambda, but checking `lineData[1] == 2` I think LINQ statement should look like this

```
scoresDesHard = list.Where(x => x[1] == "2").OrderByDescending(y => y[0]);


list.Where(foo => bar.Value1 == 123) //Always true or always false
list.Where(foo => foo.Value1 == 123) //checks each item in the list
```

Comment: It does not matter when apply sorting (its better for performance, but result will be same) - filtering returns items in same order as in source sequence

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, you are right that changing the order of the sort/where won't affect the final result.  I just always put my filters before my sort.  I don't know whether the compiler is smart enough to filter before sorting or if it will sort the full list then filter it which could be a perf problem.

Comment: @jrhutch Thanks that works. Could you possibly expand on what the problem was?

Comment: @crm the problem was that you were passing in ld into the Lambda, but you were checking lineData[1] for the difficulty.  The lineData variable wasn't changing, so it always had a difficulty of 2.  If it had been 1 you would have gotten no results.

Comment: @jrhutch ah, that was it, not order of operations. +1 from me

Comment: So Im assuming that the where clause must always precede the ordering in a `linq` statement?

Comment: @crm its better to filter out what you don't need before ordering. So with Linq to Objects you will have better performance.

Comment: No, that's just a bonus.  The real issue was the pattern 

.Where(foo => bar.Value1 == 123)

It needs to be 

.Where(foo => foo.Value1 == 123)

Comment: I just updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear what the problem was.